# Futuristic navigation

Tags: word, visual, rebus, steganography, language

This is a 3-part puzzle. Parts can be solved out of order, but, in the end, parts must be put together in order they appear (1, 2, 3) to solve the whole puzzle.

Parts are independent from each other. There is no need to combine pieces of different parts before every part is solved.

Every part contains a puzzle and its key. You'll have to figure out which is which.

**Part 1:**

[image: Part 1]

**Part 2:**

[image: Part 2]

**Part 3:**

[image: Part 3]

**Important detail:**

[image]

Hint 1:

> The keys contain what has already been done.

Comment: [Am I on the right track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwgJ0.png)? Unfortunately doing the same for R and B doesn't yield anything immediately obvious to me. For each pic I rotated the anomaly by the given number, then combined them into one pic.

Comment: @LukasRotter - I think you're a bit off the right course. I have updated the rules accordingly.

Comment: Are the images purposely in jpg format or are they supposed to be in a lossless one?

Comment: @SquareFinder - format does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer:**

> So far I see the shapes represent degrees: 120 240 360   90 180 270   60 120 180.  I'm guessing you somehow split each image into Red Green and Blue layers with a filter and then individually rotate only one of the layers the corresponding number of degrees counter-clockwise so that it overlaps revealing something.  Use the small white circle to line up the rotated images.  Must I go through with all that?  If I had to guess, I would say the revealed images are constellations.  Or something that can be used for triangulation.

Comment: Sounds about right. However, those are not constellations.